# How do I create individual flight entries from a year-long schedule?

Tags: sql, oracle, schedule

I have been given data of the schedules for all the flights in the next year and have been asked to translate the information into individual entries.

The data I have looks something like this:

```
Flight number ¦  Schedule start  ¦ Schedule End  ¦  Day of Week  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234                 4 Nov 2019          3 Dec 2019          123  7           
1234                 7 Nov 2019          2 Dec 2019             56             
1234                 3 Dec 2019          7 Mar 2019          1    7
```

---

It is basically the schedule for each flight by day of the week between the listed time period (schedule start and end date). I need to convert this into individual entries (like what you would see on airport screens, but for the whole year that i have been given data for):

`Departure date¦ Departure time¦ Flt number¦ Origin ¦ Destination`

---

using the schedule information above. I have absolutely no clue how to start, can someone give me a few ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm sorry I did not mention before, but I also have more information about flight departure and arrival time, origin and destination and aircraft type

Comment: Is the input data an Oracle table, or a text file?

Comment: The input data you posted seems a bit scrambled, and doesn't provide all the information necessary to write the query. So it's not surprising you're finding it hard to start - unless you have more data haven't posted?

Comment: Adding to @APC's comment - how would you know what the departure time, origin, and destination are? In addition, the data in the `Day of Week` column doesn't make sense to me. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button and add the needed information. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I've just put in random input information because of confidentiality, but the columns are the same. I have another table in Oracle which links flight number to origin and destination, so that is fine. Basically the day of the week information tells me that the flight time is X:XX PM on days 1 2 3 and 7 of the week, say. And on days 4 and 5 it is Y:YY AM.

Comment: @APC its my first time ever posting on a tech forum so I dont know how it works and the social conventions. Can you please not get so worked up? Just tell me what I'm doing wrong. I was already really anxious about asking questions to the tech community. Im just trying to find out how to start and the logic I can use, not the full solution because my task is more complicated than the question I've asked. The aviation industry is very competitive and we arent allowed to discuss anything to another team, let alone someone online. I was trying to be extra cautious with the information I let out.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some information missing in your base table that you need for your solution, but here is the basic idea of how you can solve such problem:

```sql
WITH "YEAR" AS (SELECT '2019' "YEAR" FROM dual)
   , "DAYS" AS (SELECT TO_DATE("YEAR"||'0101', 'YYYYMMDD') + LEVEL - 1 "DAY"
                  FROM "YEAR"
                 CONNECT BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE("YEAR"||'0101', 'YYYYMMDD') + LEVEL - 1, 'YYYY') = "YEAR")
   , dat(flight_no, sch_start, sch_end, day_of_week) AS
     (SELECT 1234, DATE'2019-11-04', DATE'2019-12-03', '1237' FROM dual UNION ALL
     SELECT 1234, DATE'2019-11-07', DATE'2019-12-02', '56' FROM dual UNION ALL
     SELECT 1234, DATE'2019-12-03', DATE'2020-03-07', '17' FROM dual)
SELECT d."DAY"
     , dat.*
     , TO_CHAR(d."DAY", 'D')
  FROM "DAYS" d
  JOIN dat 
   ON d."DAY" BETWEEN dat.sch_start AND dat.sch_end
   AND INSTR(day_of_week, TO_CHAR(d."DAY", 'D')) > 0
```

The query for "DAY" gives you all days of the year as `DATE`. Then you join them to your flight data using the schedule interval and day of week as conditions.

Comment: Thank you! I think I get the logic you are using, I'll try it out and see how it goes.I'm sorry, I do have more information about flight departure and arrival time, origin and destination and aircraft type, but that's about it.

Answer (score -1):

like this

```
with shed as
(select 1234 fn, to_date('04.11.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') SSt, to_date('03.12.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') SEnd, '1237' DOW from dual
union all 
select 1234 , to_date('07.11.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') , to_date('03.12.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') , '56'  from dual
union all 
select 1234 , to_date('02.12.2019','dd.mm.yyyy') , to_date('07.03.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') , '17'  from dual),
d as
(select trunc(sysdate,'YEAR')-1+level dt from dual
connect by level<365)
select s.fn,s.sst,s.send,d.dt from shed s
join d on d.dt between s.sst and s.send and instr(s.dow,to_char(d.dt, 'd'))>0
```